# URLConnection to RSS feed returns null

Tags: java, xml, rss, urlconnection

I want to develop a simple RSS reader but ran into a minor issue. Some RSS feeds simply return nothing when I try to load the feed using an URLConnection wile others do. This is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/new/.rss?sort=new");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

This code returns nothing, while it does show an rss feed when viewing in the browser. When I enter another feed, like "http://feeds.feedburner.com/tweakers/" it returns the correct feed.

What am I missing? Is the reddit .rss system using send redirects or something in that fashion that my URLConnection can't handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the same problem as here: [Java URLConnection returns null for valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43485297/java-urlconnection-returns-null-for-valid-url)

Reddit redirects your http url to https and your code doesn't handle the redirection. Use `https://www.reddit.com/r/technology/new/.rss?sort=new` instead.

When you handle all these issues (networking, feed parsing) and edge cases in your code, your RSS reader is not simple anymore :)